# Passing a variable to PHP with jQuery .load

Tags: php, jquery, variables, load

I have a page ("main.php") which loads content from an external PHP file ("rpc.php"). Using the below syntax on main.php successfully pulls in content from rpc.php:

```
$("#portfolioContent").load("rpc.php?o="+day+"");
```

On rpc.php I have an if statement (part of a long switch function), as follows:

```
if ( $pagename == "home" ) {
break;
}
```

This break is not occuring because the variable has not been set. rpc.php is used by various parent pages so the variables need to be set on those. On a parent page I have tried using the following code to attempt to set the variable and pass it to rpc.php but to no avail:

```
$("#portfolioContent").load("rpc.php?o="+day+"$pagename="home"");
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this,

```
$("#portfolioContent").load("rpc.php?o="+day+"&pagename=home");
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
$("#portfolioContent").load("rpc.php?o="+day+"$pagename="home"");
```

to this

```
$("#portfolioContent").load("rpc.php?o="+day+"pagename="home");
```

then access the variable with `$_GET['pagename']`

Comment: The first part of your code didn't seem to work but the $_GET['pagename'] part was very helpful, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. Try this:

```
$("#portfolioContent").load("rpc.php?o="+day+"&pagename=home");
```

Notice i substituted the `$` with a `&`

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

To access variables from the URL in PHP just do:
`$_GET['variablename']`

For example, with the URL http://www.example.com?hello=hellWorld

```
echo $_GET['hello'];
```

would print `helloWorld`

Also, you use `&` to separate variables, not `$`